# Using Geodatabase Annotation in ArcView 3.2?

Tags: shapefile, annotation, arcview-3

I've been asked to take a parcel layer (shapefile) that contains house numbers and create an annotation layer so the house numbers are displayed in a separate annotation layer rather than a label to the parcel layer.

They'd like the ability to move and rotate the house numbers for readability.

Is there a way to create an annotation layer for ArcView 3.2 that will do this?

I've experimented with exporting a couple different ways and it loses it's usability once it comes outside the geodatabase in which I originally created it.

Will ArcView 3.2 even read a geodatabase?

Answer (score 4):

ArcView 3.2 can only access data in an Enterprise geodatabase through an ArcSDE connection.

It cannot read data in personal or file geodatabases.

Even with an enterprise geodatabase I'm not sure 3.2 can do anything with annotations, I never tried personally.

Comment: That's what I thought I was seeing as I searched online for the solution to this.

Comment: (+1) 3.2 can read annotation layers but cannot create them. It *can* create, move, and rotate text, but such things are stored only as graphics in a .apr file, which is unreadable by other software. I recall posting an AV 3.x extension on the ESRI support site that will take such a set of labels and record all essential information in a shapefile (as attributes), including size, font, orientation, color, grouping levels, etc.  However, to make use of that output one would need to write similar software for the target platform to convert the shapefile back into annotation.

Comment: Has anyone ever exported annotation out to a CAD file that results in the labels being added as line features?  I wonder if this would be an alternate solution?  I don't have a copy of ArcView 3.2 to test my theories so I need to research what formats I can safely send them.

Comment: You can convert the CAD in ArcView 3.2 to Lines - turn the CAD Reader ON http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=54527